# Type "only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here" when exporting

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a file called `types.ts` which has all my types in. I want to export some of these, like so:

```
export type Example {
  something: string;
}
```

I have another file called `index.ts`, which is the entry point for my code. I want to export the Example type. When I try the following:

```
import { Example } from "./types";

export default {
  Example
}
```

I get the following error:

> 'Example' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value
> here.ts(2693)

I'm not sure how to export a type from another file correctly. I have also tried the following:

```
export * from "./types";
export { Example } from "./types";
```

But this doesn't work as it's not part of the export, due to my `export default` which contains other stuff, however this might be an entirely different issue if this is the correct way to do it.

What's the correct / best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do

```js
export default {
  Example
}
```

...you're exporting an object literal with an `Example` property (written with shorthand notation) as the default export of a module. That means it's expecting `Example` to be a variable whose value will be copied to the `Example` property of the object being exported. But in your case, `Example` is a type, not a variable.

If you want to export `Example` as the default export of a module, you'd do it like this:

```js
export default Example;
```

If you want to export `Example` as a named type export, you don't use `default`:

```js
export { Example };
```